# Как спрарсить текст из места, выделенного серым

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

[image]

```
import  requests
from xml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
HOST='https://www.muztorg.ru/'
URL='https://www.muztorg.ru/category/studijnye-mikrofony'
HEADERS={
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'
}
def get_html(url,params=''):
    r=requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS,params=params)
    return r
html=get_html(URL)
def get_content(html):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    items=soup.find_all('section', class_='product-thumbnail')
    micerophone=\[\]
    for i in items:
        micerophone.append(
            {
                'name':i.find('div',class_='title').get_text(strip=True),
                'price':i.find('p',class_='price').get_text(strip=True),#тут пытаюсь спарсить цену 5\xa0590р.выдаёт
                'img':HOST+i.find('img').get('data-src')


            }
        )
    return micerophone
print(get_content(html.text))
```

Comment: imfleisch, проверьте мой ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал функцию, которая из текста оставит только нужное, например только цифры:

```
def get_number(tag) -> int:
    value = tag.get_text()
    value_int = ''.join(c for c in value if c.isdigit())
    return int(value_int)
```

Использование при заполнении ключа `price`:

```
def get_content(html):
    ...
    for i in items:
        micerophone.append(
            {
                'name':i.find('div',class_='title').get_text(strip=True),
                'price': get_number(i.find('p',class_='price')),
    ...
```